# Symfony2 call functions from multiple twig extensions in one twig

Tags: symfony, twig

I have two twig extensions and a twig. I need functions from both the twig extensions in one twig. What is the way to differentiate that from which extension the function is called.

Right now, I'm using this method `driverId|getDriverNameFromId`
and it is giving me error!

Below is the code for driver extension:

```
<?php

namespace abc\CoreBundle\Extension;

use Doctrine\Common\Persistence\ManagerRegistry;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerInterface as Container;
use abc\CoreBundle\Entity\CostAllocation;
use abc\CoreBundle\Entity\Driver;

class DriverExtension extends \Twig_Extension {

    protected $mr;
    protected $container;

    public function __construct(ManagerRegistry $mr, Container $container) 
    {
        $this->mr = $mr;
        $this->container = $container;
    }

    public function getFilters() 
    {
        return array(
            new \Twig_SimpleFilter('getDriverNameFromId', array($this, 'getDriverNameFromId')),
        );
    }

    public function getName() 
    {
        return 'driver_extension';
    }

    /**
     * get updated columns
     *
     * @param Integer $driverImportId
     *
     * return array
     */
    public function getDriverNameFromId($driverImportId)
    {
        return $this->container->get('core_process_import')->getName($driverImportId, 'DriverImport');
    }


}
```

And similarly I have a core extension.

In my twig, when I call

```
    {% if driverImport.id|getDriverNameFromId|length > 0  %}
{% endif %}
```

It gives me error

```
Unknown "getDriverNameFromId" filter in CoreBundle:DriverImport:list.html.twig at line 88?
```

Below is the code for services.yml

```
_core.services.invoice.extension.class: abc\CoreBundle\Extension\InvoiceExtension
    _core.services.driver.extension.class: abc\CoreBundle\Extension\DriverExtension


invoice.twig.extension: 
        class: %_core.services.invoice.extension.class% 
        arguments: [@doctrine, @service_container] 
        tags: 
            - { name: twig.extension }
    driver.twig.extension: 
        class: %_core.services.driver.extension.class% 
        arguments: [@doctrine, @service_container] 
        tags: 
            - { name: twig.extension }
```

Comment: Provide the code to expose the issue.

Comment: please refer to the question again. I've updated the description with code

Comment: why not put all your filters/functions in the same class?

Comment: You can have as many extensions as you want/need. So there being two, is propably not the problem. It more seems like `DriverExtension` issn't loaded at all, and thus the filter is not available.

Comment: Because that will flood the class with code and that is a bad practice!

Comment: @Yoshi, how to load it then?

Comment: Just follow the [manual](https://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/templating/twig_extension.html#register-an-extension-as-a-service), and check if/what you missed.

Comment: I followed everything in the same way , the function is called when I put it in CoreExtenison but stops working and gives error when I put it in DriverExtension

Comment: @Rooneyl The namespace is just good practise. It all depends on the service definition.

Comment: @anujeet did you register this extension as service with proper tag?

Comment: yes @dragoste, I did!

please refer to my latest code with services.yml configuration

Comment: A few things you can try. Add some simple debug code in the extensions constructor, just to see if the extension is instantiated. Or/and maybe clear the symonfy cache. Are you running in dev mode? (e.g. under `app_dev.php`?).

Comment: There's something else, because I've put your code into my project (just changed what the filter does because I don't have your entities obviously) without modifications and it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've tested your code in my project and it works fine, so it's something else.

I think that your service configuration is not imported.

If you added it in **bundle's** `services.yml` file (not the main one in `app/config/services.yml`), then make sure that you've imported this file in `config.yml` file.

Assuming your service configuration is in

```
src/CoreBundle/Resources/config/services.yml
```

make sure you've imported it at the beggining of `app/config/config.yml` file:

```
imports:
    - { resource: parameters.yml }  // |
    - { resource: security.yml }    // |=> default ones
    - { resource: services.yml }    // |
    - { resource: "@CoreBundle/Resources/config/services.yml" } //new one
```

Comment: I made a typo in services.yml.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

First get the namespace right (as per there suggestion for best pratice); it should be namespace `Smartshore\CoreBundle\Twig` for any Twig extension classes.

Make sure you have declared the classes correctly in your services.yml.
E.g.

```
driver_extension.twig.extension:
        class: Smartshore\CoreBundle\Twig\DriverExtension
        arguments: ["@my.injected.services"]
        tags:
           - { name: twig.extension }
myotherclass.twig.extension:
        class: Smartshore\CoreBundle\Twig\MyOtherTwigExtension
        arguments: ["@security.context", '@kernel', '@router']
        tags:
           - { name: twig.extension }
```